# Update individual file in Idea changes panel

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, migration

I just moved from Eclipse to Idea.
In eclipse whenever i want to sync my repository with Svn i simply do Team->Synchronize with repository. It gives me list of all folders and files for incoming and outgoing changes. I sometimes update project, folder or only some files inside folder instead of all files in folder from Synchronize perspective. In Idea in changes panel i can see all changes in incoming tab after i refresh. But i not able to update individual files in folder. I can only see update project button in changes panel.
Is there any way to update individual files from changes panel itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do.

Right click the file that you want to get updates for in the Changes panel. Click Subversion > Update File.

I have attached a screen shot.

[image: Update Single File in Intellij]

Comment: I can see update file option when i right click file from Editor. From changes panel i didn't see this option. I am using Idea 13.0.3 community edition.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using Idea 13.1.2 Ultimate Edition. I looked at a feature comparison (Community to Ultimate) to try to find out if file-only update is not included in the Community version, but I could not find confirmation on this. If it's not cost-prohibitive, you may try to upgrade to the Ultimate version to gain this feature.